# Assigning addition of two complex input value to a variable in python

Tags: python, complex-numbers, calculation

I want to print the summed, divided, multiplied values to the variable for a simple complex calculator. So here my code sample

```
num1=input("Enter a number: ")
num2=input("Enter another number: ")

#complex(num1)= 2.44+-77.3333j
#complex(num2)= 2.44+-77.3333j
result=complex(num1) + complex(num2)
print(result)
```

I tried j instead of on console, Its seems something wrong in my way. Because I keep getting the same error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "...", line 14, in <module>
    result=complex(num1) + complex(num2)

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

I tried many options but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enter the numbers in [the exact format Python expects](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#complex).

```
num1 = complex(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = complex(input("Enter another number: "))

print(f"{num1} + {num2} = {num1 + num2}")
print(f"{num1} - {num2} = {num1 - num2}")
print(f"{num1} * {num2} = {num1 * num2}")
print(f"{num1} / {num2} = {num1 / num2}")
```

works just fine (floating-point precision notwithstanding):

```
$ python3 socom.py
Enter a number: 2.44-77.3333j
Enter another number: 6.83+15j
(2.44-77.3333j) + (6.83+15j) = (9.27-62.333299999999994j)
(2.44-77.3333j) - (6.83+15j) = (-4.390000000000001-92.3333j)
(2.44-77.3333j) * (6.83+15j) = (1176.6646999999998-491.5864389999999j)
(2.44-77.3333j) / (6.83+15j) = (-4.208867770125335-2.0791044579970688j)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need to assign the result of the operation for further works. I need to know. Additionally, this code does not accept '5+7i' and ' 2.44+-77.3333j' (minus imaginary) complex values which I didn't understand properly. my occupation electronic and we use 'i' format for represantation complex numbers generally by the way.

Comment: As I linked, the exact format Python accepts uses `j`, not `i`, and the simplified `-` instead of `+-`. You can of course add some string replacements to fix these before you pass things to `complex()`.